Having difficulties with WP cron
I am having multiple problems with my simple testing cron snippet.
First, it is not doing its job, which is updating theme option field.
Second, when checking in the Cron Events plugin dashboard, seems like it is not triggering every 3 minutes, as it should do.
Here is the code:
class RedirectionChecker {
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter('cron_schedules', [ $this, 'add_every_three_minutes' ]);
        add_action('init', [ $this, 'schedule_event' ]);
        add_action('redirection_checker_hook', [ $this, 'redirection_checker_func' ]);
    }

    public function add_every_three_minutes($schedules) {
        $schedules['every_three_minutes'] = [
            'interval' => 180,
            'display'  => __('Every 3 Minutes')
        ];
        return $schedules;
    }

    public function schedule_event() {
        if (!wp_next_scheduled('redirection_checker_hook')) {
            wp_schedule_event(time(), 'every_three_minutes', 'redirection_checker_hook');
        }
    }

    public function redirection_checker_func() {
        update_option('test_option', 'success');
    }
}



You can add debugging statements to your code to verify if the cron job is being scheduled and executed correctly. like you can use error_log() to log messages to the PHP error log:
public function schedule_event() {
if (!wp_next_scheduled('redirection_checker_hook')) {
    error_log('Scheduling redirection_checker_hook');
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'every_three_minutes', 'redirection_checker_hook');
}
}

public function redirection_checker_func() {
error_log('Running redirection_checker_func');
update_option('test_option', 'success');
}

